# Why does my parallel command print “Starting” and ”Finished“ at the same time?

Tags: bash, command-line, gnu-parallel

```
ls *.txt | parallel 'echo Starting on file {}; mkdir {.}; cd {.}; longCMD3 ../{} > /dev/null; echo Finished file {}'
```

This one liner partially works, except longCMD3 takes about 3 minutes, but the first and second echo commands are printed almost at the same time.
I tried putting in

```
wait
```

before the final echo, but that made no difference.

How can I ensure that the final echo is only printed once longCMD3 is complete?

**Here's an example**

Assume I only have 4 cores:

```
ls
foo1.txt foo2.txt foo3.txt foo4.txt foo5.txt foo6.txt
```

**What I expected:**

```
Starting on file foo1.txt
Starting on file foo2.txt
Starting on file foo3.txt
Starting on file foo4.txt
```

then at least 2 minutes should pass for longCMD3 to finish on one of the files

```
Finished file foo1.txt
Starting on file foo5.txt
```

**But what I get is:**

```
Starting on file foo1.txt
Finished file foo1.txt
Starting on file foo2.txt
Finished file foo2.txt
Starting on file foo3.txt
Finished file foo3.txt
Starting on file foo4.txt
Finished file foo4.txt
```

This continues for all 6 files. And the Start and Finished statements are printed simultaneously for each file. But a few minutes are expended  between each file.

Comment: It isn't clear what you want here. For **each .txt file**, `echo Finished file foo.txt` runs after `longCMD3 ../foo.txt` has finished. But it's to be expected that “Finished” for one file appears before all the files have been processed: otherwise why would you parallelize?

Comment: OK, I hope it's clear now.

Comment: If the finishes are arriving approximately on time, but the starts are arriving just before the finishes, and the process monitor is saying that you have 8 processes running for sometime (Please confirm). Then it is probably an output buffer problem. That is that the output is being buffered, and output all at the same time. This may be by design, to so that outputs are not mixed up.

Comment: @ctr-alt-del, you are indeed correct. As mentioned by Gilles, the output was being buffered by parallel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each file, the commands `echo Starting on file foo.txt`, `mkdir foo`, `cd foo`, `longCMD3 ../foo.txt > /dev/null` and `echo Finished file foo.txt` run sequentially, i.e. each command starts after the previous one has finished.

The commands for different files are interspersed. By default, the parallel command runs as many jobs in parallel as you have cores.

However the *output* of the commands is not interspersed by default. This is why you don't see a bunch of “Starting” lines and then later the corresponding “Finished” lines. Parallel groups the output of each job together. It buffers the output until the job is finished. See the description of the `--group` option in the manual. Grouping doesn't make sense in your case, so turn it off with the `--ungroup` (`-u`) option, or switch to line grouping with `--line-buffer`.

Some other corrections:

- [Parsing ls is not reliable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Pass the file names to `parallel` directly.
- If `mkdir` fails, you shouldn't proceed. If any command fails, you should arrange for the job to fail. An easy way to do that is to start the job script with [`set -e`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin).

```
parallel --line-buffer 'set -e; echo Starting on file {}; mkdir {.}; cd {.}; longCMD3 ../{} > /dev/null; echo Finished file {}' ::: *.txt
```

Comment: The -u option worked beautifully. And I'll also change the way the file names are passed to parallel.

Comment: @Glubbdrubb `-u` does not guarantee half-lines to mix. It is unlikely to happen in your case (because your lines are < 4 KB long), but I suppose `--line-buffer` is _really_ what you are looking for.